# Can you enable Unicorn NewItemsOnly for specific folders?

Tags: unicorn

I am using Unicorn to serialise/synchronise Sitecore items from lower environments (developer local) to higher environments (production).

I would like to use the NewItemsOnly configuration (see link below) to prevent items changed on higher environments from being overwritten but I don't want to do this across the entire solution and all folders. Can you configure NewItemsOnly to apply to certain folders so that other folders continue to be fully synchonised? i.e. updates, deletes are also synchronised for most folders but for some folders only newly created items are synchronised?

https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/Standard%20Config%20Files/Unicorn.Configs.NewItemsOnly.example

Answer (score 3):

### Yes you can

You can define the `Evaluator` (i.e. `NewItemsOnly`) on a per-configuration basis.

So to answer your question; yes you can. But you would need to group your content into separate configuration elements.

```
<configurations>
    <configuration name="Sample New Items Only Configuration">
        <evaluator type="Unicorn.Evaluators.NewItemOnlyEvaluator, Unicorn" singleInstance="true"/>

        ... your predicates here
    </configuration>

    <configuration name="All My Other Stuff">
        ... with no Evaluator defined, default is used

        ... more stuff here
    </configuration>
</configurations>
```